# Is it possible to perform a custom multi-touch gesture in an Xcode UI Test?

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

I'm trying to test the behavior of an iOS app as it responds to complex multi-touch gestures.

The only multi-touch testing capability I've been able to find are two convenience methods on [XCUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement): `pinch(withScale:velocity:)` and `rotate(_:withVelocity:)`. However, this is not powerful enough for my needs. (Also, the rotate gesture does not work consistently.)

**In an Xcode UI test, is there a way to customize the paths of each touch in a multi-touch gesture?** Something similar to how [XCUICoordinate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuicoordinate) allows you to customize the path of a press-and-drag gesture?